# Modal-titles, how to have multiple and not have the same title for all modals

Tags: html, modal-dialog

I currently have three modals which pop up when a button is pressed, however they all share the same modal title, which is the first one set of the three. Being that the three modals are related to different topics, i would like to set three different titles, however they stay the same. So there are three modals, all pop ups work and close correctly and display information, however their title remains the same as the first one set, thanks in advance for help with this most likely simply problem (please ignore spelling too, i'm yet to throw everything through a spelling checker; the three modals are below:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
   </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Scratch Programming course</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Our Scratch programming course runs through the first semester of school, a ten week course with two lessons per week.</p>
      <p>
      Designed to teach key skills, such as: Problem solving skills, logical thinking, and most importantly, having fun!
      </p>
      <p>
      Scratch enables the children to learn a variety of key skills for programming, which are transferable to other subjects. Conveyed in a fun and approachable manor (their favourit cartoons and games), so that its possible to have fun while they learn key concepts.
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
  </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>   

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;    
       </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Stencyl Programming course</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Our Stencyl programming course runs through the second semester of school, a ten week course with two lessons per week. The same as that of the Scratch course.</p>
      <p>
      Designed to cement and develop key skills, such as: Problem solving skills, logical thinking, programatical approach to thinking and also thinking outside of the box.
      </p>
      <p>
      Stencyl enables the students to develop their skills in regards to programming, and also aid in the development of their other skills which are transferable. Stencyl is still an approach used to remain underwhelming on the students behalf, conveyed once again in a fun and simple way, rather than throwing the children in the deep end, allowing them to further cement their knowledge before jumping in to their first programmatical language, Python.
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
 </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- Modal -->
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;    
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Python Programming Course</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Our Python programming course runs through the third and final semester of the school, a ten week course with two lessons per week. The same as that of the Scratch course.</p>
      <p>
      Designed to cement and develop key skills, such as: Problem solving skills, logical thinking, programatical approach to thinking and also thinking outside of the box.
      </p>
      <p>
      Stencyl enables the students to develop their skills in regards to programming, and also aid in the development of their other skills which are transferable. Stencyl is still an approach used to remain underwhelming on the students behalf, conveyed once again in a fun and simple way, rather than throwing the children in the deep end, allowing them to further cement their knowledge before jumping in to their first programmatical language, Python.
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-   
    dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the duplicate id's on the modals.  Each id should be unique.

Also, you have two extra ending div tags.  One after the first modal and the other is after the third modal.

Comment: Spot on, thank you very much for your reply. I knew it would be something as simple as this, thanks